# Different views with unique pagination?

Tags: 7, views

I have 2 block (column) with 2 different content type. I need to do a unique pagination.
How can I do?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable ajax on both blocks, in the view advanced options.

In the pager settings of each block you must be sure that both blocks are using the same pager ID.

As both blocks are using the same pager ID, and the page is sent through the URL (not ajax), each block will asume that that is the page it has to show.